# How to perform two operations on one activity in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to implement a search in my Android application.
In this page, first I am displaying a user list and then performing a search on the user list. Both are in the same activity. In the following manner, I am getting intent and some values from the previous page. When I display the user list, all the values are coming. But while performing search, `spaceId` gets lost and becomes null. I need this value.

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle receiveBundle = intent.getExtras();
spaceId = receiveBundle.getString("spaceId");
```

What should I do to get this value?

**Edit:**

```
String spaceId;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle receiveBundle = intent.getExtras();
        spaceId = receiveBundle.getString("spaceId");
        String URLTicketList = String.format(getString(R.string.URLTicketList, spaceId));
        RestClient client = new RestClient(URLTicketList,
                this.getApplicationContext());
        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TabSettings ts = new TabSettings();
        ts.setSelTab(0);
        String response  = client.getResponse();
        tickets = parseTicketList(response);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            searchResult=getMatchingStrings(tickets,query);
            this.ticket_adapter = new TicketAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.ticket_details_row,searchResult);
            setListAdapter(this.ticket_adapter);
        }
        else  {
            this.ticket_adapter = new TicketAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.ticket_details_row, tickets);
            setListAdapter(this.ticket_adapter);
        }

    }
```

**getMatchingstrings()**

```
ArrayList<Ticket> getMatchingStrings(ArrayList<Ticket> list, String regex1)     {
        ArrayList <Ticket> listClone = new ArrayList<Ticket>(); 
            for (Ticket string : list) {
                    if(string.getAssignedTo().equals(regex1)){
                listClone.add(string);
                }
            }

          return listClone;
        }
```

Comment: user370305:Actually i do not need this spaceId while searching, but Activity.class called again when i go for search and spaceid gets null this time, that causes the problem. I need only user list for seaching, but on click on search activity called again, and list null

Comment: this method , perform search on tickets, and returns the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your activity is recreating. So you are not getting the value of spaceID after recreation. Then do this thing as below.

```
public String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_Pref";

Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String spaceId_value = receiveBundle.getString("spaceId");

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

if(spaceId_value == null) {
     spaceId_value = settings.getString("spaceId", "");
}
else {
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("spaceId", spaceId_value);
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

edit :

I am editing your code.

Which part i have edited, i have mentioned that part as edited. Carefully see what i have changed and do that thing in your code. Then let me know.

```
     String spaceId;
     public String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_Pref";  //edited part

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //editing start

         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
         if(receiveBundle != null) {
             spaceId = receiveBundle.getString("spaceId");
             if(spaceId == null) {
                 spaceId = settings.getString("spaceId", "");
             }
             else {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                 editor.putString("spaceId", spaceId);
             }
         }

        //editing end

        String URLTicketList = String.format(getString(R.string.URLTicketList, spaceId));
        RestClient client = new RestClient(URLTicketList,
            this.getApplicationContext());
        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TabSettings ts = new TabSettings();
        ts.setSelTab(0);
        String response  = client.getResponse();
        tickets = parseTicketList(response);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            searchResult=getMatchingStrings(tickets,query);
            this.ticket_adapter = new TicketAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.ticket_details_row,searchResult);
            setListAdapter(this.ticket_adapter);
        }
        else  {
            this.ticket_adapter = new TicketAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.ticket_details_row, tickets);
            setListAdapter(this.ticket_adapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: this time am getting spaceId as "", but i need previous value.

Comment: And tell me are getting the bundle as null or not?

Comment: debatati: i added editor.commit();, and now am not getting spaceId as null :)

Comment: Please just paste your full code of the activity you are using. Then only i can tell you whats the problem. And tell me that when the activity is recreated are you getting the bundle null? Please do these two things.

Comment: debarati: i have added my whole code, and i get null value for spaceid when i click for search button, on emulator

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("spaceId");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are firstly loading your list in activity,you have to save that spaceId in some SharedPreference variable for further use.And while reloading activity with search result,you can find that Id from SharedPreference variable previously saved.

Be sure,you overwrite that variable as and when you firstly load list in your activity to meet your needs cleanly.

Also you have to get spaceId from intent like:

```
int spaceId=0;
if(getIntent().hasExtra())
    spaceId=getIntent().getStringExtra("spaceId");
```

Doing this wont give you excpetion when you reload the same activity with no extras to your intent.

Or,you will have to pass this spaceId along with intent you are using to reload the same activity for showing search result.

Hope,you get the point!

Comment: please go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

If u relaunching the same activity while performing search,u will lost that value. If u r doing so,while relaunching also pass that spaceId to the relaunching activity also using intent.putextra() method

Answer (score 0):

as in your question and comments i guess you are getting problem if your activity is recreated

add following code in manifest file under your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

your activity will not be created again

and then use the value of spaceID where you need

Comment: Used this, but dint work for me :(. actually  i dnt need spaceid again, i want only tickets to search, but because activity is recreated am getting this spaceid null and thats y tickets list null

Comment: it works for me its still not clear what you are trying to do